# Selenium Python confuses elements which are not existing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a supermarket
(https://www.sklavenitis.gr/eidi-artozacharoplasteioy/psomi-typopoiimeno/)
I have the urls on a file and read them and iterate through them.
But the selenium is confused about some elements which are not existing e.g.

on the second link which is on sale the price is correct but afterwards like the third or fourth link which are not in discount it still prints the value of the second link
and again when something is in discount all is okay, but if is not in discount get the previous discounted value. Should I close my driver in every iteration and reopen it?
I saw some posts and they didn't do that for that I am asking

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
delay = 10
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    myElem =WebDriverWait(theDriver,
    delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='product- 
    detail__title']")))
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='product-detail__left']").find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='deleted__price']").text.replace(",", ".")
```

Edit#1
Sorry for the confusion I want to scrape the prices before the discount and after the discount.( If there is not a discount it just print the current price).
My problem is on the items which are not in discount, selenium shows that somehow there is a discounts for that reason I added the class  product detail left to be more strict about scraping but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the pricess of each item using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) in a single line of code inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.sklavenitis.gr/eidi-artozacharoplasteioy/psomi-typopoiimeno/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.nvcookies__right button.nvcookies__button.nvcookies__button--primary.consent-give"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.price")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.sklavenitis.gr/eidi-artozacharoplasteioy/psomi-typopoiimeno/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.nvcookies__right button.nvcookies__button.nvcookies__button--primary.consent-give"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='price']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['1,29 €/τεμ.', '1,45 €/τεμ.', '0,78 €/τεμ.', '1,82 €/τεμ.', '1,82 €/τεμ.', '1,57 €/τεμ.', '2,24 €/τεμ.', '2,62 €/τεμ.', '2,38 €/τεμ.', '1,32 €/τεμ.', '1,88 €/τεμ.', '2,24 €/τεμ.', '2,08 €/τεμ.', '1,18 €/τεμ.', '1,67 €/τεμ.', '2,08 €/τεμ.', '0,78 €/τεμ.', '2,57 €/τεμ.', '1,52 €/τεμ.', '1,62 €/τεμ.', '2,28 €/τεμ.', '2,05 €/τεμ.', '2,38 €/τεμ.', '2,40 €/τεμ.']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I edited the question, I want to scrape both the discounted and the current price. But in selenium in the products which are not discount, it shows that have a discount

Comment: AFAIK, current price is the discounted price :) did you mean the original price? Then how would you show 2 prices for one item?

Comment: I want the original and the current, for this which are not in discount I would just print the current and -1 (that shows is not in discount, I would do that with try catch)